# Why the plugin not working?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a basic plugin.but when I am trying to execute its not working. So far I have this .

Hide   Copy Code

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {       

        this.fadeOut('normal');

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now when I try to call this

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    $(".img").myPlugin ()
});
```

It does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine i can guess you forgot to make a reference of jQuery library:

```js
(function ($) {

    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {       

        this.fadeOut('normal');

    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img").myPlugin()
});
```

```css
.img{width:100px; height:100px; background:yellow; border:red solid 1px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='img'>Img Element</div>
```

Comment: I am working offline so I have preinstalled jQuery .it still does nothing .

Comment: Yeah I have added my code after jq lib.and for info if I erase the plugin do it simpler like .... $(document).ready (function (){ $(".img").fadeOut ('normal')});..it works fine